# Pandas Cumulative Time Series Range in Data Frame

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I'm looking to have an "expanding" date range based on the values in a starttime and endcolumn.

If any part of a record occurs in a prior record, I want to return a starttime that is the minimum of the two starttime records and an endtime that is the maximum of the two endtime records.

These will be grouped by an order id

```
Order starttime             endtime                 RollingStart            RollingEnd
1   2015-07-01 10:24:43.047 2015-07-01 10:24:43.150 2015-07-01 10:24:43.047 2015-07-01 10:24:43.150
1   2015-07-01 10:24:43.137 2015-07-01 10:24:43.200 2015-07-01 10:24:43.047 2015-07-01 10:24:43.200
1   2015-07-01 10:24:43.197 2015-07-01 10:24:57.257 2015-07-01 10:24:43.047 2015-07-01 10:24:57.257
1   2015-07-01 10:24:57.465 2015-07-01 10:25:13.470 2015-07-01 10:24:57.465 2015-07-01 10:25:13.470
1   2015-07-01 10:24:57.730 2015-07-01 10:25:13.485 2015-07-01 10:24:57.465 2015-07-01 10:25:13.485
2   2015-07-01 10:48:57.465 2015-07-01 10:48:13.485 2015-07-01 10:48:57.465 2015-07-01 10:48:13.485
```

So, in the above example, Order 1 has an initial range that runs from 2015-07-01 10:24:43.047 to 2015-07-01 10:24:57.257 and then another one from 2015-07-01 10:24:57.465 to 2015-07-01 10:25:13.485

Note that while the starttimes are in order, the endtimes are not necessarily due to the nature of the data (there are short term events and long term events)

In the end, I only want the last record of each orderid,rolling start combination (so in this case, the last two records

I tried

```
df['RollingStart'] = np.where((df['endtime'] >= df['RollingStart'].shift()) & (df['RollingEnd'].shift()>= df['starttime']), min(df['starttime'],df['RollingStart']),df['starttime'])
```

(this obviously doesn't include the order id)

But the error I receive is

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Code to replicate follows:

```
from io import StringIO
import io

text = """Order   starttime               endtime
1       2015-07-01 10:24:43.047  2015-07-01 10:24:43.150
1       2015-07-01 10:24:43.137  2015-07-01 10:24:43.200
1       2015-07-01 10:24:43.197  2015-07-01 10:24:57.257
1       2015-07-01 10:24:57.465  2015-07-01 10:25:13.470
1       2015-07-01 10:24:57.730  2015-07-01 10:25:13.485
2       2015-07-01 10:48:57.465  2015-07-01 10:48:13.485"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', parse_dates=[1, 2])
df['RollingStart'] = np.where((df['endtime'] >= df['RollingStart'].shift()) & (df['RollingEnd'].shift()>= df['start']), min(df['starttime'],df['RollingStart']),df['starttime'])




df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', parse_dates=[1, 2])


df['RollingStart']=df['starttime']
df['RollingEnd']=df['endtime']
df['RollingStart'] = 
np.where((df['endtime'] >= df['RollingStart'].shift()) & (df['RollingEnd'].shift()>= df['starttime']),min(df['starttime'],df['RollingStart']),df['starttime'])
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 731, in     __nonzero__
.format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to return a value based on a value that isn't set yet,

`df['start'] =...conditions... df['start'].shift()`

looks to me like you are trying to set a condition on a column that Pandas doesn't know anything about.

If you are just trying to set the "start" value as the latest time in these columns, try building a statement with or statements, or a make a temporary array and use max, if you are just trying to get the latest time

`df['start'] = np.where(max(df['enddatetime'],df['startdatetime'],))`

If the above is way off, do you have the code to reproduce this df so I can see if I get the same error?

Comment: I'm trying to get the earliest starttime (and then I will try to get the latest end time) for each overlapping series .. not sure I follow what you are proposing, my apologies

Comment: Complete code to reproduce updated inline - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Version 1

```
NaT = pd.NaT
df['Rolling2']     = np.where(df['starttime'].shift(-1) > df['endtime'], NaT,'drop')
df['Rolling2']     = df['Rolling2'].shift(1)
df['RollingStart'] = np.where(df['Rolling2']  =='drop',None,df['starttime'])
df['RollingStart'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RollingStart']).ffill()
df['RollingEnd']   = df['endtime']
del df['Rolling2']
```

Version 2.

```
df['RollingStart'] = df['starttime']
df['RollingEnd']   = df['endtime']
df['RollingStart'] = np.where(df['RollingEnd'].shift()>= df['starttime'] ,pd.NaT , df['RollingStart'])
df['RollingStart'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RollingStart']).ffill()


  Order               starttime                 endtime            RollingStart              RollingEnd
0      1 2015-07-01 10:24:43.047 2015-07-01 10:24:43.150 2015-07-01 10:24:43.047 2015-07-01 10:24:43.150
1      1 2015-07-01 10:24:43.137 2015-07-01 10:24:43.200 2015-07-01 10:24:43.047 2015-07-01 10:24:43.200
2      1 2015-07-01 10:24:43.197 2015-07-01 10:24:57.257 2015-07-01 10:24:43.047 2015-07-01 10:24:57.257
3      1 2015-07-01 10:24:57.465 2015-07-01 10:25:13.470 2015-07-01 10:24:57.465 2015-07-01 10:25:13.470
4      1 2015-07-01 10:24:57.730 2015-07-01 10:25:13.485 2015-07-01 10:24:57.465 2015-07-01 10:25:13.485
5      2 2015-07-01 10:48:57.465 2015-07-01 10:48:13.485 2015-07-01 10:48:57.465 2015-07-01 10:48:13.485
```

Comment: I gave you two solutions.. which one a you referring you.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the rollingend to work with this logic, given that the end times may occur out of sync.. Would really appreciate any help you can provide.. Thanks